# Why is GridFS Query Returning Null / Default Values in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I want to query for the GridFS file info and metadata but it is return null or default values except for the Id.

I made a model of the structure:

```
public class GridFSFileEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public int ChunkSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    public string Md5 { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Then I queried for it:

```
_gridFSFileEntities = _database.GetCollection<GridFSFileEntity>("GridFSFileEntity.files");
var results = _gridFSFileEntities.Find(doc => true).ToList();
```

I verified via Mongo Compass that the other fields have values but I cannot get it to populate in C# except for the Id.

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: I followed a video to upload files to a bucket. All that works fine. Now I just want to query for the metadata as you would a normal collection.

Comment: I suggest reviewing official MongoDB documentation for both uploading and downloading.